# Freennode Weechat Android Protocol error and Failed to connect error

Tags: 9.0-pie, f-droid

I'm using [weechat-android](https://github.com/ubergeek42/weechat-android) that I installed using f-droid and trying to connect to freenode in order to join an irc server. I am able to connect freenode on my Windows 10 PC using mIRC as expected. Not able to do so on Android after following this doc https://freenode.net/kb/answer/chat.

This is the exact setup I used when I get the protocol error.

[image]
[image]

This is the exact setup I used when I get the failed to connect error.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Where do you got the information about the server `freenode.net:8001 from? When I search for freenode I only get irc.freenode.net:8001 or chat.freenode.net:6697 for the [SASL connection](https://freenode.net/kb/answer/weechat).

Comment: I must have mixed those up I got some of that information from this [kb article](https://freenode.net/kb/answer/chat) about connecting to freenode, but wasn't sure about the ports.

Comment: When I set my relay password, relay port to `8001` and host to `irc.freenode.net:8001` I still get a Error: Protocol error message.

Comment: I assume you have to use one of the TLS ports, not the insecure plain text ports.

Comment: I'm not sure what ports where used. I used both mIRC and compiled Weechat from source on Ubuntu, both abstracted the ports I believe.

Comment: Have you executed the commands form the manual I have linked in my first comment?

Comment: The one from _Configuring SASL for WeeChat_ right? Would I need to root my phone to run these commands?

Comment: What makes you think so? Root is never mentioned anywhere you should just type in the commends into your chat program.

Comment: The chat program is running on my Android phone. How would type these commands in on my Android phone?

Comment: It is a chat program. Type the commands into the chat.

Comment: This is the program I am using https://f-droid.org/packages/com.ubergeek42.WeechatAndroid

Comment: Have you read the Quickstart info about the relay server? See also my edited answer.

Comment: I have, I think my blocking issue is I am having trouble getting this to work with my Android app, but all of the guidance assumes I have access to a CLI where I can run these commands. Which I don't have access to in Android unless I'm root.

Comment: You have to execute these commands in the Weechat program on your PC/server.

Comment: Okay I think I see now, I misunderstood. I run these commands on my desktop from your answer. Then the Android app connects to Weechat through the ports I expose on my local network?

Comment: Seems to be the way this app works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113555/discussion-between-robert-and-greg).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: According to the Quickstart guide Weechat-Android is not a chat-program, it is only a UI for a chat program running on your server:

> Weechat-Android is a relay client, that is it's not a standalone
> client, but one that connects to your copy of WeeChat running on your
> server. You can connect the two in a number of ways, listed below.

Therefore if you just install the app on your phone it is not usable. You still need an own server on the Internet where your Weechat program is executed.

> You can connect to freenode by pointing your IRC client at
> chat.freenode.net on ports 6665-6667 and 8000-8002 for plain-text
> connections, or ports 6697, 7000 and 7070 for TLS-encrypted
> connections.
> Connect to chat.freenode.net

https://freenode.net/kb/answer/chat

Alternatively there is a Weechat how-to for setting the correct server: https://freenode.net/kb/answer/weechat

```
/server add freenode chat.freenode.net/6697 -ssl
/set irc.server.freenode.sasl_mechanism PLAIN
/set irc.server.freenode.sasl_username <nickname>
/set irc.server.freenode.sasl_password <password>
/save
```